# Symfony 3 shared hosting error 500

Tags: php, symfony, cpanel

I am trying to deploy my symphony application on a shared hosting but I keep getting error `500`.

I structured the app, bin, `src` and vendor on the parent folder then I changed the web folder to public_html on `cpanel`.

when I run the `URL` using `example.com/app_dev.php` it works fine.

However when use example.com i get error `500`, so I toggled the `PHP` option on `cpanel` to `display_error` and this is the error I am getting:

> Warning: include_once(/home/kaftenh1/public_html/../var/bootstrap.php.cache):  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kaftenh1/public_html/app.php on line 7
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/kaftenh1/public_html/../var/bootstrap.php.cache' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear') in /home/kaftenh1/public_html/app.php on line 7
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "elao.error_notifier.listener" has a dependency on a non-existent service "swiftmailer.mailer.notifier". in /home/kaftenh1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /home/kaftenh1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(42): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(Array) #1 /home/kaftenh1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php(36): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition)) #2 /home/kaftenh1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compi in /home/kaftenh1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php on line 58

Thanks for

Comment: Does the file at `/home/kaftenh1/var/bootstrap.php.cache` exist? Note the `..` in the path goes upa level, removing `public_html` from the path

Comment: you can try to chmod 777 for var directory.

Comment: @Milk thanks alot it worked changed the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Really appreciate. From your answer and comments i figured the what the problem was. I changed the path in app.php to point where the bootstrap.php.cache is.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
 $loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once '/home/kaftenh1/var/bootstrap.php.cache';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try run command:

`composer install`

Or

`php composer.phar install`

I hope this video tutorial help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HchMW8EhWPU

Comment: Sorry please i am kind of new to the shared hosting. where can i run the command on cpanel. Because i already installed the composer during development

Comment: you can watch tutor

Answer (score -1):

If you have ssh access to the server you can then login to the server and open the website project and run

```
 composer install
```

If you dont have ssh access try to use [webconsole](http://web-console.org) .